# Hide options based on date in contact form 7

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I'm building a contact form in Contact Form 7 that has a field with date selections like this:

```
[select* Startdate id:startdate class:startdate "09-06-2020" "11-09-2020" "02-11-2020"]
```

Is there any way to hide the date options with dates in the past?

Comment: Is the select option is hardcoded in the backend or a dynamic one which created on the fly?

Comment: It's a dynamic one.

Comment: If it is a dynamic one. Please explain how it's dynamically created through any plugin or shortcode or hooks?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to solve this problem,

Solution #1, server-side using the [Smart Grid-layout CF7 plugin extension](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf7-grid-layout/).  It has a `[dynamic_dropdown]` tag field which allows you to build a dropdown select field programmatically using a filter.

```
add_filter('cf7sg_dynamic_dropdown_custom_options', 'filter_options',10,3);
function filter_options($options, $field_name, $form_key){
  if($form_key != 'my-form') return $options; //check this is the correct form.
  if($field_name != 'custom-dropdown') return $options; //check this is the correct field.
  $options = array(); 
  //you can fetch a list of dates from your DB is needed.
  $dates = array("09/06/2020", "11/09/2020" ,"02/11/2020");
  $now = time();
  //load your options programmatically, as $value=>$name pairs.
  foreach($dates as $date){
    if(strtotime($date) > $now){
      $options[$date]=$date;
    }
  }
  return $options;
}
```

Soltution #2, client-side using javascript,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  const now = new Date();
  $('select#stardate option').each(function(){
    let date = $(this).val();
    if(date.getTime() < now.getTime()) $(this).remove();
  });
});
```

This will remove all select option elements that are older than now.